# I can't add 3 parameters to authenticate and generate token using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle and Symfony

Tags: jwt, symfony5, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am building a REST API and I want to add one more parameter for the validation of the token. By default username and password are used, I need to add a third parameter, but my code didn't work. I used the following example: [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle---validating-data-in-the-jwt-payload](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-data-customization.md#eventsjwt_decoded---validating-data-in-the-jwt-payload)

1.I created the folder "src\EventListener" and the file "JWTDecodedListener.php" inside that folder.

2.Then, I added the following content to that file:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\JWTDecodedEvent;

class JWTDecodedListener
{
    /**
     * @param JWTDecodedEvent $event
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function onJWTDecoded(JWTDecodedEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        
        $payload = $event->getPayload();

        if (!isset($payload['contract']) || $payload['contract'] !== $request->getContract()) {
            $event->markAsInvalid();
        }
    }
}
```

3.I also inserted the settings in the file "\config\services.yaml":

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    acme_api.event.jwt_decoded_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\JWTDecodedListener
        arguments: [ '@request_stack' ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: lexik_jwt_authentication.on_jwt_decoded, method: onJWTDecoded }
```

4.When testing the application on the postman making the request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check" with the new field, the contract field was not considered in the validation. I did it as follows:

```
{
    "username":"9VJ203Q4A53DH8I",
    "roles":["ROLE_USER"],
    "contract": "1122334455",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

My project tree looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AseIh.png)

I don't know what is missing or what I did wrong. I want the token to be returned only if the username, contract and password are correct.

Comment: Is the event fired? Can you put some var_dump() and exit() there to see?